# How to count Each rating using mongoose aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I calculate rating count based on each rating using mongoose aggregate function? I have the collection below:

```
[

{
    "ProjectName":"AAA",
    "Emp":[
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"1",
                "Rating":2.5
            }
        },
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"2",
                "Rating":2
            }
        },
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"2",
                "Rating":2.5
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "ProjectName":"BBB",
    "Emp":[
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"1",
                "Rating":3
            }
        },
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"1",
                "Rating":4
            }
        },
        {
            "Emp":{
                "EmpID":"2",
                "Rating":4
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    ..
}
```

]

I am expecting the response below:

```
[{

    "projectName":"AAA",
    "Rating":[
        {
            "Rate":0.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":1,
            "Count":0,
            "Percentage":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":1.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":2,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":2.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":3,
            "Count":1
        },
        {
            "Rate":3.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":4,
            "Count":2
        },
        {
            "Rate":4.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":5,
            "Count":0
        }
    ]
},
{
    "projectName":"BBB",
    "Rating":[
        {
            "Rate":0.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":1,
            "Count":0,
            "Percentage":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":1.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":2,
            "Count":1
        },
        {
            "Rate":2.5,
            "Count":2
        },
        {
            "Rate":3,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":3.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":4,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":4.5,
            "Count":0
        },
        {
            "Rate":5,
            "Count":0
        }
    ]

},{...}]
```

Ho do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$unwind": "$Emp" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "projectName": "$ProjectName",
                "rate": "$Emp.Emp.Rating"
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.projectName",
            "Rating": { 
                "$push": {
                    "Rate": "$_id.rate",
                    "Count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "projectName": "$_id", "Rating": 1
        }
    }
];

Model.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, result) {
    if (err) { /* handle error */ };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```